# Rails association with custom column data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, orm

I am using ruby 2.4 and Rail 5.1

I have taken over a new project which has the following two models:

1. `User` primary field: `id`
2. `Account` primary field: `id`, foreign key: `userid`

The challenge is, the data for `userid` is a combination of the real id of user and prefix of a specific character as per the account type.

Few examples of `userid` data:

```
userid
-------
s1001
s1002
s1003
a1004
```

`s1001`: `s` stands for the students type of account and `1001` is the real id of `users` table.
`a1004`: `a` stands for the admin type of account and `1004` is the real id of the `users` table.

**Question:**
How I can define one to one relationship between these two models?

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: can you confirm that the foreign key is `user_id` and not `userid` ?

Comment: yes, its a `userid` not `user_id`. Thanks.

Comment: Why would you want to do this in the first place? A foreign key column should just be a reference - the values should be the primary keys of the other table. Just add another column to the accounts table that describes the type of the account. If this is legacy code your first task should be to fix the garbage db design.

Comment: ActiveRecord does not AFAIK support composite foreign keys and I doubt your database does either so you won't be able to use foreign key constraints for important stuff like referential integrity.

Answer (score 1):

This is not going to fly. ActiveRecord does not support composite foreign keys and neither do most RDBMS:es. There is just no freaking way AR will be able to link the two unless `accounts.userid == users.id`. Consider if you're joining from the users side - how is it supposed to know if the foreign key is `a1001` or `s1001` (or should it maybe match both)?

This was definitely someone's clever idea that was really quite stupid.

What you need to do is use two columns to store the data instead. You can get this working by changing the database schema and data with a set of migrations.

First create a column for the type.

```
class AddAccountTypeToAccounts < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    add_column :accounts, :account_type, :string
  end
end
```

You could potentially use an integer or a Postgres enum type column instead. Then populate the column with data from the `userids` column:

```
class SetAccountsAccountTypes < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def up
    Account.update_all(
      'account_type = LEFT(accounts.userid, 1)'
    )
  end
end
```

Use a SQL CASE statement if you want to store something better than just `a` or `s`.

Then cleanup the values in `accounts.userid`:

```
class FixUserids < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    Account.update_all(
      'userid = SUBSTRING(userid, 2)' # SQL is 1 indexed
    )
  end
end
```

This will let you setup the associations since you now actually have a real foreign key column.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :account, foreign_key: 'userid'
end

class Account < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, foreign_key: 'userid'
end
```

Once you have some tests you should change the column type of `accounts.userid` to bigint or whatever type matches `users.id`. AR and maybe your db will still work with a type mismatch but its hardly ideal. You may also want to change the column name to `user_id` which matches the rails conventions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's quite interesting and informative one. We have millions of records in both the tables. Also, adding userid after updating it, will require a considerable code change.

Comment: This also just effects one of the tables.

Comment: And the only real option here if you want to stick your head in the sand is custom joins like `JOINS accounts ON (accounts.userid = CONCAT('a', users.id) OR accounts.userid = CONCAT('s', users.id))` but thats just madness. Especially if the the table has a million rows.